# IIS not rewriting URL for Angular

Tags: angularjs, iis, url-rewriting

I want to enable HTML5 mode to true in my Angular app so I don't have to use a URL of localhost:100/#/movies instead of localhost:100/movies but I am using IIS so I'm having to use a rewrite. The problem is rewrites, or any rules for that matter, simply don't work if I write them into my web.config but they seem to work when I make them through the IIS GUI... Despite this, rewriting with the following still doesn't work, even when I make it in IIS...

```
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
```

I just want to rewrite all URLs to Angular's own routing. Why is this not working? I have the URL Rewrite module installed, I've tried restarting my machine, restarting IIS, changing the rewrite expression. Nothing works. Not even if I match a specific word like "movies" to rewrite it to "/" or something.

Comment: Why should the Webserver effect the HTML5 mode URL's? Those URLs are handled by the client (browser) and not by the server. You should not need to change the IIS settings at all. Does your browser support HTML5 URL mode? It should work even if you have no host and open your application in a browser directly from filesystem.

Comment: I need IIS to handle the API that I retrieve data from...